# Are the Jacques Pépin videos worth it for a novice?

Tags: resources, learning

I have Pépin's "Complete Techniques" book and find it interesting but a little hard to follow at times. I wonder if the DVD "The Complete Pépin" is a worthwhile addition. The reviews on Amazon are mixed, but also from the general public and not from a group of self-selected cooking knowledge exchangers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

being a chef, i would have to answer that ANY VIDEO is always a help. Technique you learn over time with repition. But all the shows (maybe Pepin, and Childs are favored a bit more)are going to show you 'their' techique.  learn from it. expand from it. then make it your own.